# Can't install php5.6-gd in docker container

Tags: php, docker, debian, gd, php-5.6

I want to create a container with php5.6-fpm but when I run it, PHP there doesn't have such needed extensions as e.g. gd and some others needed for wordpress. I want to install it manually inside the container `fpm`. 
`docker exec -it fpm bash`
It turns out that Debian 9 installed there and I can't install php5.6-gd for `E: Package 'php5.6-gd' has no installation candidate`! I tried adding ondrej repository, but it's not helpful at all.

Is there any other ways to get container with php5.6-fpm installed and add some extension to it?

Comment: Debian 9 uses PHP 7, not 5. You could install php7.0-gd, or just php-gd, which depends on the current version.

Comment: @KarstenKoop, I simply pull php:5.6-fpm and create container of it. Then I run bash and it has debian 9. Can I change it maybe so that there would be Ubuntu 16.04 for example? If I pull nimmis/apache-php7 I have php 7 with all needed extensions, and it runs on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/laradock/php-fpm/blob/master/Dockerfile-56) you can find working Dockerfile for what you need.

Relevant part:

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
(...)
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libz-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev

(...)
# Install the PHP gd library
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd \
        --enable-gd-native-ttf \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
        --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Comment: I love you :P
Thanks a lot :))